# Why are my promises not executing properly in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise

I'm developing a simple validated form component using React & React-Bootstrap. I've decided to implement some of my functionality using promises so that I have flexibility in chaining them together. But for some reason, my `then` clauses are not being executed. Here's the (simplified) code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl, HelpBlock } from 'react-bootstrap';
import validate from 'validate.js';

export default class EmailInput extends Component {
    // define the propTypes required by this component
    //
    static propTypes = {
        validation:  PropTypes.object,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // initialize the state for this component
        //
        this.state = {
            value: this.props.value,
            hasChanged: false,
            validationErrors: [],
        };
    }

    updateState(newState) {
        console.log('-------- updateState', this.state, newState);
        return new Promise(
            (resolve) => {
                console.log('-------- updateState promise', this.state, newState);
                this.setState(
                    newState,
                    () => {
                        console.log('-------- updateState in setState callback', this.state);
                        resolve();
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }


    onChange(event) {
        console.log('-------- onChange', this.state);
        this.updateState({ value: event.target.value })
            .then(() => {
                // **** this is not being executed ****
                console.log('--------- DONE');
            });
    }

    onBlur() {
        // basically the same as the onChange event
    }

    render() {

        const hasErrors = this.state.hasChanged && this.state.validationErrors.length>0;

        const validationState = hasErrors ? 'error' : null;
        const feedback = hasErrors ? (<FormControl.Feedback />) : null;
        const helpBlock = hasErrors ? (<HelpBlock>{this.state.validationErrors.join('. ')}</HelpBlock>) : null;

        return (
            <FormGroup validationState={validationState}>
                <ControlLabel>{this.props.label}</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.value}
                    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                    onBlur={this.onBlur.bind(this)}
                />
                {feedback}
                {helpBlock}
            </FormGroup>
        );
    }
}
```

A few words about my environment: I'm using Webpack & the Babel transpiler and executing this code in the context of a Karma test suite.

In short, what I've done is created a "promisified" `setState` method called `updateState`. It simply returns a new promise that is resolved when the `setState` callback is executed. As you can see, I've sprinkled `console.log` statements throughout the code so I can track what's going on.

What I expect to see is the "onChange" log message, followed by the three "updateState" messages, and then the "DONE" message.

What I actually see is the "onChange" message, followed by the "updateState" messages, and nothing else. The state is being updated correctly, though. I should also mention that I've tried it with `catch` handlers for all the promises, but no errors are caught either.

I'm probably overlooking something blindingly obvious, but I can't afford to tear out any more of my hair over this. Can someone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I was unable to get a minimal reproduction [here](https://jsbin.com/yukomib/1/edit?html,js,console,output), which as you can see works as intended. Can you try removing components and stripping things down until you have a minimal reproduction?

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve]?

Comment: What is `Promise`, do you use any polyfill or do you rely on the native implementation? If the latter, what browser are you executing this in?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm going to have a closer look at @rossipedia's code a little later with an eye to reducing my example.

Comment: @Bergi - the code that is giving me problems is running under node.js on the command line, since I'm running a Karma test suite. Thus, I *assume* it's using node's native implementation - however, I am also using Babel to transpile the code, which might be providing a different implementation.

Comment: I suggest moving asynchronous code outside your React components and managing it in something like Redux or Flux. It will be easier to reason about your components, and more predictable, if you can treat them as synchronously-rendering views. React removed `isMounted` because it was leading to async code in components. https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html is a good read.